# Blender Fur particle mess up

Tags: rendering, particles

I edit my fur and everything is well, but when I render it, it as if switches to a different particle and renders it weird, then it changes everything I edited to something glitchy looking, but when I try to edit it, it goes back to what I was editing first. It only renders the glitchy one though.

[image]

Edit 1:

Here's the [blend](https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0BytBiDl4tMgdc0t1VG5RRE5lMGs&export=download)

Comment: Hmm, seems to be doing the same thing just with a biggeer number of particles. [![Img.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OdSRU.png)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OdSRU.png)

Comment: can you [upload](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) your .blend file?

Comment: when I switch Rendered value to 10 it looks kinda the same in [render](http://imgur.com/oSm1blK)

Answer (score 1):

It might be because of children tab settings:

[image]

Make sure values in display and Render are the same.
[image]

Same cube in 3D view and in Render